# How come the xenon $6s$ state is metastable?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, orbitals

I'm having some trouble puzzling out some aspects of the electronic excitation spectrum of xenon, and I'd appreciate some help with it.

[This classic paper](https://doi.org/10.1126/science.1198450) ─ the first one to pioneer the use of laser-induced electron holography ([preprint](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00553330/file/1198450.pdf)) ─ uses a fairly vanilla-type experiment as far as strong-field physics go, but one notable feature is that they required a target with a low ionization potential, so they use, in their words,

> metastable ($6 s$) xenon atoms,

which they produced using electron-impact excitation.

I was trying to understand this state (with the vague goal in mind to see if there are states with even lower $I_p$'s available), but I ended up getting even more confused, and from looking at the electronic configuration, this feels like it shouldn't be metastable at all.

The [NIST ASD](https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/ASD/levels_form.html) lists several states that fit this description,

> $$
> \begin{array}{cccc}
> \text{configuration} & \text{term} & J & I_p \\\hline 
> 5p^5(^2\mathsf{P}_{3/2}^\mathrm{o})6s
> & ^2[3/2]^\mathrm{o}
> & 2 & 8.315\:\mathrm{eV}
> \\ & 
> & 1 & 8.437\:\mathrm{eV}
> \\
> 5p^5(^2\mathsf{P}_{1/2}^\mathrm{o})6s
> & ^2[1/2]^\mathrm{o}
> & 0 & 9.447\:\mathrm{eV}
> \\ & 
> & 1 & 9.569\:\mathrm{eV}
> \end{array}
> $$

the first of which is the first excited state of xenon, and whose $I_p$ (given by subtracting its excitation energy from the ground-state xenon $I_p$ of $12.13\:\rm eV$) matches the one reported in the paper, at $3.8\:\rm eV$.

Here's my question, though: I really don't see how this state can be metastable against dipole radiative decay down to the ground-state $5p^6$ $^1\mathsf S$ configuration, particularly since that transition would ostensibly just involve moving one electron from a $6s$ shell to a $5p$ one, and, at least in isolation from other electrons, that's a classic example of an allowed transition.

This is further backed up by the lines database at ASD, which quotes the existence of such a transition at a wavelength of $146.9610\:\rm nm$ coming from the $^2[3/2]^\mathrm{o}$ state, and one at $129.5588\:\rm nm$ coming from the $^2[1/2]^\mathrm{o}$ state. Both transitions have a nonzero 'relative intensity' (presumably?) means that they are indeed observed in emission, if I understand correctly, and they have [transition probabilities](https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/ASD/Html/lineshelp.html#OUTAKI) of around
$$
A_{ki}\approx 2.5 \times 10^8 \:\rm s^{-1},
$$
corresponding to lifetimes of around $4\:\rm ns$, which is pretty short for dipole lines (for scale, it's a bit longer lifetime than the Lyman alpha $2p$-$1s$ line in hydrogen).

So, what gives? Huismans et al. claim that

> The metastable xenon atoms were exposed to a train of 5000 mid-IR laser pulses separated by 1 ns,

and that doesn't square at all with the lifetimes as I've derived them from the ASD.

Can anyone see what I'm missing here?

Comment: “I really don't see how this state can be metastable against dipole radiative decay down to the ground-state...” -- sorry, I may be missing something, but would it involve J=2 to J=0?